# Identification code and img src property

Tags: javascript, html

```
<pre lang="HTML">
<img alt="" name="Code_Verify" id="Code_Verify" align="top" 
     src="/ipcast_os/login_auth/display_verify"/>
</pre>
```

`display_verify` is a function that outputs identification code.
Why is the `src` property not a directory of an image file?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by, "Why does the SRC property is not a directory of image file?" Could you please be a bit more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content-type or mime-type of the attribute is not enforced by the client (your browser). In fact a web server may return a valid image for that request even if there is not an extension like `.jpeg` or `.png` or whatever.

It's up to your server to respond with the proper image, when a `GET` request is made to the path `/ipcast_os/login_auth/display_verify`.

If you provide additional information about your javascript we can help you more easily.